# terminating input at the end of input in java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, eof

How to terminate scanner without entering any EOF character like this problem in codeforces.com(http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/661/C). 
Which gives in each line of input an integer and after n line
(n isn't a specified number by problem) the input hasn't any new line. so give some way to determine there is no more lines in the input!

Comment: Read with a timeout I suppose? How is input given, manually to STDIN?

Answer (score 0):

in the example you posted is too broad, you can for sure define a timeOut timer to close the Scanner, but I think something more simple would do that for beginner levels like catching if the input is empty (which is some how entering a EOF character too IMHO)

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi type some numbers, but just enter to finish");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String c = scan.nextLine();
    while (!c.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        System.out.println("nice, try again ");
        c = scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("ok bye");
}
```